# How do I extract viewport from a pdf and modify an annotation's bounding rectangle according to the viewport?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, viewport

I have implemented functionality to add link annotation to any pdf using pdfbox. It works well for most of pdfs, but for some pdfs it not placing markups at correct coordinates. And when I opened that pdf in some pdf editor, it gave me warning that the pdf contains an untitled viewport which might affect measurements for that pdf. So, I feel viewport is most probably causing the problem. Is there a way that I can modify the coordinates of markup according to viewport, so that it is placed at correct location in pdf. Here is a [link](https://cmicglobal-my.sharepoint.com/personal/ecm_archive_cmic_ca/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=0b5967610d144479a9e044369e444b260&authkey=AQ-OIpM7NEvyZ5hM9jjD6s4&e=d54117e2e854477f9b8bdc0cad1d063d) to a pdf which contains the viewport.

According to Tilman's suggestion, I extracted the C entry from viewport's measure dictionary. And tried to modify rectangle's coordinate, but they are not getting added at the right location.Below is the code that I tried. Also, the viewport does not have effect on annotations, but it is causing problem when I try to draw something into the pdf.

```
COSArray vps = (COSArray)page.getCOSObject().getDictionaryObject(COSName.getPDFName("VP"));
if (vps != null)
{
    for (int v = 0; v < vps.size(); ++v)
    {

        COSDictionary vp = (COSDictionary)vps.getObject(v);
        PDViewportDictionary viewportDict = new PDViewportDictionary(vp);
        PDRectangle vpRect = viewportDict.getBBox();
        PDMeasureDictionary measureDict = viewportDict.getMeasure();
        PDRectlinearMeasureDictionary rectilinearDict = new PDRectlinearMeasureDictionary(measureDict.getCOSObject());
        bool pointLieInVP = UtilityClass.RectangleContainsPoint(new PointF(leftX, bottomY), vpRect);
        if (pointLieInVP)
        {
            COSArray xArray = (COSArray)measureDict.getCOSObject().getDictionaryObject(COSName.getPDFName("X"));
            float xScale = 1;
            if (xArray!=null)
            {
                xScale = ((COSFloat)(((COSDictionary)xArray.getObject(0)).getDictionaryObject(COSName.getPDFName("C")))).floatValue(); 
            }
            leftX /= xScale;
            rightX /= xScale;
            COSBase yObj = measureDict.getCOSObject().getDictionaryObject(COSName.getPDFName("Y"));
            if (yObj != null)
            {
                COSArray yArray = (COSArray)yObj;
                float yScale = ((COSFloat)(((COSDictionary)yArray.getObject(0)).getDictionaryObject(COSName.getPDFName("C")))).floatValue(); 
                bottomY /= yScale;
                topY /= yScale;
            }
            else
            {
                bottomY /= xScale;
                topY /= xScale;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the [link](https://cmicglobal-my.sharepoint.com/personal/ecm_archive_cmic_ca/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=09f304dba11904452a90abb248ecd3e69&authkey=AQwaIJNbHzJZTrfFJCnuGok&e=206e8355d01a4721b999fffbda7482d3) to pdf markups are added without adjusting for viewports. The 5 red colored markups are added at bottom right end of the page. But they should have been placed over the link annotations in the pdf which are placed at correct positions. And here is the [link](https://cmicglobal-my.sharepoint.com/personal/ecm_archive_cmic_ca/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=02d7e4107e9d74545802f5e383f915527&authkey=Afuy8zLVP6gWYlmCODsw_j8&e=3da6f57a4bde4c8c84baa32cbc58e153) for pdf , in which markups are placed after modifying their coordinates using the above code. The markups do not appear at all.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I have added link to file which contains viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code (which does not avoid ClassCastExceptions) will show you the viewports in each page:

```
try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("S115-STRUCTURALHIGH ROOF FRAMING(WEST)ENLARGED PLANS.pdf")))
{
    for (int p = 0; p < doc.getNumberOfPages(); ++p)
    {
        PDPage page = doc.getPage(p);
        COSArray vps = (COSArray) page.getCOSObject().getDictionaryObject(COSName.getPDFName("VP"));
        if (vps != null)
        {
            for (int v = 0; v < vps.size(); ++v)
            {
                COSDictionary vp = (COSDictionary) vps.getObject(v);
                PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle((COSArray) vp.getDictionaryObject(COSName.BBOX));
                System.out.println("Viewport " + vp.getString(COSName.NAME) + ": " + rect);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to adjust annotations is up to you... most likely, these should be inside the bbox. All you need to do is to adjust the rectangle of the annotations.

Comment: I tried to modify the coordinates according to viewport's measure dictionary, but, it is not working. I have added the code that I used, in the question, please have a look.

Comment: Your code does not modify the annotation rectangle. You're doing something with the viewport instead.

Comment: The leftX,bottomy,topy, rightx are the coordinates for the markup rectangle. Also, viewport  does not have any affect on annotation, it only affects whatever draw in the pdf.

Comment: Please add link to the PDF with your annotation and the PDF with the annotation modified.

Comment: Added the links, please have a look.

Comment: The red dots are not annotations. Removing the annotations still brings the red dots. And your "markups.pdf" file is not related to the first file you had. The link areas are "hot" at the correct places.

Comment: Initially, I believed that annotation along with the markups that I was drawing using PDPageContentStream were getting affected by viewports. But then I found that only markups are getting affected.

Comment: So the whole question is mostly moot now, isn't it? Btw your content stream starts with `0.06 0 0 0.06 2 2 cm`. So this scaling would also apply to whatever you append later. See the javadoc of the PDPageContentStream constructor.